# Asp net System.Web.CachedPathData.GetPhysicalPath(VirtualPath virtualPath) Exception

Tags: asp.net, exception

I have this error in my website. it occurs not to specific page but to all.

```
at System.Web.CachedPathData.GetPhysicalPath(VirtualPath virtualPath) 
at System.Web.CachedPathData.GetConfigPathData(String configPath) 
at System.Web.CachedPathData.GetConfigPathData(String configPath) 
at System.Web.CachedPathData.GetConfigPathData(String configPath) 
at System.Web.CachedPathData.GetVirtualPathData(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean permitPathsOutsideApp) at System.Web.HttpContext.GetFilePathData() 
at System.Web.HttpContext.GetConfigurationPathData() 
at System.Web.HttpContext.GetSection(String sectionName) 
at System.Web.Configuration.HttpConfigurationSystem.GetSection(String sectionName) 
at system.Web.Configuration.HttpConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String configKey) 
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName) 
at System.Configuration.PrivilegedConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName) 
at System.Net.Configuration.SettingsSectionInternal.get_Section() 
at System.Net.WebUtility..cctor()System The type initializer for 'System.Net.WebUtility' threw an exception.
```

I have no idea what is it, and how to handle it.
Thanks,

Comment: Does your server run on Windows Server 2012? This KB entry shows a similar error message: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2848799/en-us.

Comment: You should be adding some background about the .net version, server environment, did this ever work? Have you changed something recently.

Comment: are you using IIS or your local VS developpement server ?

Comment: It works fine on the local VS, But in 3 different server the error raised. (2008,2010 servers, VPS server and not)

Comment: Similar error may occur when you render the same page through webBrowser class in C#

Answer (score 3):

The problem is described in: [kb 2848799](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2848799/en-us)

to fix it you need to contact microsoft for a hotfix. The short term solution is to recycle the application domain.

> **ASP.NET issue 1**
>
> In some cases, the first call to HttpUtility in a web
>   application may cause incorrect type initialization. This leads to
>   later failures when you use HttpUtility methods. When you experience
>   this issue, you have to recycle the application domain to resolve the
>   issue. Additionally, you find the following message in the System log:
>
> Getting Error Message for Exception System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
>   (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException'
>   was thrown. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type
>   initializer for 'System.Net.WebUtility' threw an exception. --->
>   System.Web.HttpException  at
>   System.Web.CachedPathData.GetPhysicalPath(VirtualPath virtualPath)  at
>   System.Web.CachedPathData.GetConfigPathData(String configPath)  at
>   System.Web.CachedPathData.GetConfigPathData(String configPath)

Comment: Only query I have for the above hotfix is that, it says the first request might experience this error, where as I am assuming that OP is encountering this to all pages, all the time.

Comment: The explanation is not clear, if you only experince the issue on the first request. Why do you have to recycle the application domain to resolve the issue? So I quess that if it fails, it keep failing all the time.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, the first call to HttpUtility in a web application may cause incorrect type initialization. This leads to later failures when you use HttpUtility methods. When you experience this issue, you have to recycle the application domain to resolve the issue. Additionally, you find the following message in the System log

Comment: the function called automate?